# How to delete NA from the graph

Tags: ggplot2

I'm still learning R and I'm not sure why there is NA data in my graph. Considering that I have used the table function to check the variables in the column.
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJA2h.png)

Any suggestions to remove the NA variable in my graph?

Please find below sample of code(not actual dataset):

*Install and load relevant packages

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("lubridate")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("tibble")

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
```

*data frame

```
all_trips <- tribble(~start, ~end, ~start_name, ~type,
                   "2020-03-22 03:20:20", "2020-03-22 04:10:15", "A", "member",
                   "2020-03-25 01:01:07", "2020-03-25 05:09:45", NA, "member",
                   "2020-03-26 07:09:55", "2020-03-26 08:10:20", "B", "casual",
                   "2020-03-29 09:10:30", "2020-03-29 09:00:20", "A", "casual",
                   "2020-03-30 11:09:18", "2020-03-30 03:40:10", "B", "member")
```

*generate new columns

```
all_trips$date <- as.Date(all_trips$start) #The default format is yyyy-mm-dd
all_trips$month <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%m")
all_trips$day <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%d")
all_trips$year <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%Y")
all_trips$day_of_week <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%A")

all_trips$ride_length <- difftime(all_trips$end,all_trips$start)

is.factor(all_trips$ride_length)
all_trips$ride_length <- as.numeric(as.character(all_trips$ride_length))
is.numeric(all_trips$ride_length)
```

*data cleaning

```
all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_name == "NA" | 
                              all_trips$ride_length<0),]
```

*data viz

```
all_trips_v2 %>%
  mutate(weekday = wday(start, label = TRUE)) %>% #creates weekday field using wday()
  group_by(type, weekday) %>% #groups by usertype and weekday
  summarise(number_of_rides = n()   #calculates the number of rides and average duration 
            ,average_duration = mean(ride_length)) %>% # calculates the average duration
  arrange(type, weekday)    %>% # sorts
  ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = number_of_rides, fill = type)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)
```

Bar Chart:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy6IN.png)

Comment: To get a usable answer, it would be helpful to to include reproducible sample data and code that produces the ggplot with NA's.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the comment. I have added the code in the initial post. Not sure if it is enough but feel free to let me know if you need any further information. Cheers!

Comment: @StevenFelim Please add the actual code, not a picture of the code. You should provide code as a [mre], so that others can easily replicate your problem and find answers.

Comment: The answer below should sufficiently solve issue, try to incorporate into your code. Please copy and paste code as text, then highlight and press "ctrl+k" to format as code (so others can readily access).

Comment: @DavidBuck thanks David for the advise. I have added the actual code to my initial post. I only copied and pasted a portion of it as it has 100-ish lines. Please kindly let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @DanTarr thanks Dan. Adding na.rm and na.translate do make a difference, yet I still can see 'NA' on the legend. Not sure if there is an issue in my cleaning process that trigger this issue.

Comment: @StevenFelim Please add a small subset of all_trips_v2 data with suspect NA's like here: library(tidyverse)
ctable <-tribble(~Area, ~School, ~Coffeeshop, ~Hospitals, ~Parks, ~Total,
  "Washington", 142, 120, 20, 20, 302,
  "Seattle", 120, 140, 30, 40, 330)

Comment: @DanTarr Hi Dan. I have updated my initial post with more details. I have also added a link to the data set. Hopefully, it will be enough to help you diagnose and replicate my analysis. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @StevenFelim, Please add minimal reproducible dataset, a small sample that produces the error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: @DanTarr Hi Dan, I have updated it.. Seems like there is an issue with my data cleaning. Kindly advise me on this. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveFelim It works with all_trips, also start_name has NA but not used to produce ggplot

Comment: @DanTarr Yes it does exclude NA and ride_length with minus value. But for some reason,  when I run View(all_trips_v2), there are three rows with 1 NA row. And you can see the bar above (last sentence of the post).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `na.rm`and `na.translate` arguments will remove missing values from bar chart without a warning message as shown here:

```
tibble(x = rep(c('One', 'Two', 'Two', NA),2), Group=rep(c("A","B"),each=4)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x, fill=Group)) +
labs(title="Sample Group Bar Chart with NA's Removed") +
geom_bar(stat="Count", position=position_dodge(), na.rm = TRUE) +
scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response! Indeed it works! Thank you for the solution. However, do you know how to remove the 'NA' from the legend as well?